# How to generate a single python file from several proto files

Tags: grpc-python

I have a project with a proto files in a:

```
$ tree proto/
proto/
├── common
│   └── request.proto
├── file
│   ├── file.proto
│   └── file_service.proto
├── job
│   ├── job.proto
│   └── job_service.proto
├── pool
│   ├── pool.proto
│   └── pool_service.proto
└── worker
    ├── worker.proto
    └── worker_service.proto

5 directories, 9 files
```

I want to generate a one single file from `worker_service.proto` but these file has imports from common.

Is there a option in `grpc_tools.protoc` to generate one single python file?

Or is there a tool to generate one proto file?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information, I guess by generate one Python file means: instead of generate one Python file for messages (`*_pb2.py`) and one Python file for services (`*_pb2_grpc.py`), you hope to concatenate both of them into one Python file. To take a look at the generated file content, here is the  [Helloworld example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld).

Combining the two output file is currently not supported by the gRPC Python ProtoBuf plugin (unlike Java/Go). You can post a feature request and add more detail about your use case: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues